# Magento 2: this.performPayment() not working from callback function payment js

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, knockoutjs

I am creating a payment module, but I am getting issue in my payment js,My js code is below:

> app/code/Namespace/Magento/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/abc.js

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-payment-information',
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'Xyz',
        'mage/storage'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, $, ko, additionalValidators, setPaymentInformationAction, url, customer, placeOrderAction, fullScreenLoader, messageList, shippingSaveProcessor, customerData, modal, Xyz, storage) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Namespace_Magento/payment/form'
            },
            preparePayment: function () {
                var options = {
                    type: 'popup',
                    responsive: true,
                    innerScroll: true,
                    modalClass: 'namespace-payment',
                    title: '',
                    buttons: []
                };
                var popup = modal(options, $('#abc-payment'));
                $('#abc-payment').modal('openModal');
            },           
            submitCard: function() {
                Xyz.generateToken(this.callback, 'txn' + Date.now());
            },
            callback: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                this.performPayment(data);
            },
            performPayment: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                return this;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

The issue which I am facing is to call method using this.performPayment() is not working from callback() method.
callback() method is calling from submitCard() method.

I am getting this not defined.

Please help if anyone have any solution.